# Displaying a multi-column checkbox list

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I'm currently displaying my list of checkboxes like this:

```
foreach (var employee in Model.Employees) {        
    @Html.CheckBox(employee.Name);<br />   
}
```

This is great if you want one long column of checkboxes, but my list is getting long, so I want to display it in 2 or 3 columns.

Is there an easy way to do this? I know I can create a table, then put in a `for` loop for the first half of the Employees for one column, and then another `for` loop for the other half of the Employees in another column. But that seems so primitive, there has to be a simpler, cleaner way.

Comment: I don't see how using 2 or 3 columns would make the list any shorter. You would still get many checkboxes horizontally. Also grouping them in columns would make it less intuitive for the user if they don't have some logical meaning for being grouped.

Comment: There is an easier way to do this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7448678/626533

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use 2 or 3 html lists containing your checkboxes, each list appearing immediately after the next in the markup, and use css to float each list to the left.

This example will separate checkboxes in to 2 lists if there are more than 10 checkboxes:

**CSS:**

```
.multi-list 
{
    float: left;
    padding-right: 50px;
}

.clear
{
    clear: both;
}
```

**HTML markup w/ Razor:**

```
@{
    if (Model != null)
    {
        int itemCount = 0;        
        <ul class="multi-list">
            @foreach (var item in Model) {
                itemCount++;
                <li>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
                    @Html.CheckBoxFor(modelItem => item.Active)
                </li>
                if (Model.Count() > 10 && itemCount == (int)(Model.Count() / 2))
                {
                    @Html.Raw("</ul><ul class=\"multi-list\">");
                }
            }
        </ul>
        <div class="clear"></div>
    }
}
```