# Stack checkboxes for 50 states in 5 vertical columns of 10

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

In my MVC view, I've got this:

```
@foreach (var state in Model.States)
{
    <div class="checkbox">
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="SelectedStates" id="sell_@state.Value" value="@state.Value" /> @state.Text
        </label>
    </div>
}
```

Where States is:

```
public List<SelectListItem> States { get; set; }
```

That, of course, puts all the checkboxes in a single column.  I'm trying to figure out the best way to stack them in 5 columns of 10 each.  I'm hoping there  is a more elegant way than putting a counter in the `foreach` and playing with the divs when the counter hits 10.

**EDIT:**

They need to be in vertical columns.  NOT horizontal rows. (I thought that was clear from the title of the post, but maybe not.)

Any ideas?

Comment: Style them with `float: left;` and `width: 20%;`

Comment: ok, but wouldn't that put them in horizontal rows, and not vertical columns?

Comment: Client is very particular that they be stacked vertically, and not horizontally.

Comment: I think you have an answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6617021/displaying-a-multi-column-checkbox-list?rq=1

Comment: Yes. but that is not clear in your question :)

Comment: @stephen: look at the title of the post!

Comment: @SethuBala... ok (sigh) that's what I was hoping to avoid.  But maybe it's really the best / only way? Sometimes I miss the old .NET.... CheckBoxList was a great thing.

Comment: But even in CheckBoxList you have to check for the count. :) to have multiple columns

Answer (score 0):

```
<div>
@foreach (var state in Model.States)
{   <ul class="checkboxes">
            @foreach (var item in Model) {
                <li>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
                    @Html.CheckBoxFor(modelItem => item.Active)
                </li>
            }
        </ul>
}
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.checkboxes ul, .checkboxes li {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    list-style:none;
}
.checkboxes li {
    display:inline-block;
    width:20%;
}
```

**Demo** https://jsbin.com/bumomeyeki/edit?html,css,output

Comment: This will put the states in horizontal columns, not vertical rows.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the link provided by Sethu Bala, this is what I came up with.  Seems ugly, but it works:

```
 @{int i = 0;}
    <div class="col-md-1">
    @foreach (var state in Model.States)
    {
        i++;
        <div class="checkbox">
            <label>
                <input type="checkbox" name="SelectedStates" id="sell_@state.Value" value="@state.Value" /> @state.Text
            </label>
         </div>
         if (i == 10)
             {
                 @Html.Raw("</div><div class=\"col-md-1\">");
                 i = 0;
             }
    }
    </div>
```